# How to convert VisualState xaml to c#

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, visualstatemanager

**Visual States in XAML**

```
<VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
           <VisualStateGroup x:Name="SectionHeader">
               <VisualState x:Name="SectionHeaderNormal">
                   <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                       <AdaptiveTrigger MinWindowWidth="1200"/>
                   </VisualState.StateTriggers>
                   <Storyboard>
                       <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="txtUser" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Style">
                           <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource usernameStyle}"/>
                       </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                       <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="txtName" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Style">
                           <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource nameStyle}"/>
                       </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                   </Storyboard>
               </VisualState>
        </VisualStateGroup>
</VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
```

I need to create this XAML code programmatically via C# code.

**Current code**

```
            var vsg = new VisualStateGroup();
            var vs = new VisualState();
            vs.StateTriggers.Add(new AdaptiveTrigger
            {
                MinWindowWidth = 1200.0
            });
```

How do I create storyboards and add these properties?

Comment: Give it a try and then seek help here with specific question when you get stuck.

Comment: XAML esssentially serializes objects as XML, so anything you see as an element or attribute also exists as a class or property. You already used the `StateTriggers` property. There is a `Storyboard` property as well. Did you try this? Did you encounter a problem?

Comment: If you look at the documentation of `VisualState`, you can see that it has `[ContentPropertyAttribute("Storyboard")]`, so you can assign the storyboard to the property of same name, even though in XAML it is not wrapped in `<VisualState.Storyboard>...</VisualState.Storyboard>`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use the `VisualState` in code behind, you should be able to add `Setter` to `SetterBaseCollection` of the `VisualState`. Also we should be able to add the `VisualState` to the `VisualStateGroup`. Then we can add the `VisualStateGroup` to our control.

To get the `Style` in code behind, we should be able to use the `FrameworkElement.Resources`.

For example:

```
<Page.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="usernameStyle" TargetType="TextBlock">
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red" />
    </Style>
</Page.Resources>

<Grid Name="MyGrid" Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <TextBlock Name="txtUser" Text="555555" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"></TextBlock>
</Grid>
```

The code behind:

```
public MainPage()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
    var vsg = new VisualStateGroup();
    var vs = new VisualState();
    Style appButtonStyle = (Style)this.Resources["usernameStyle"];
    vs.StateTriggers.Add(new AdaptiveTrigger
    {
        MinWindowWidth = 1080
    });

    vs.Setters.Add(new Setter
    {
        Target = new TargetPropertyPath
        {
            Path = new PropertyPath("(TextBlock.Style)"),
            Target = txtUser
        },
        Value = appButtonStyle
    });

    vsg.States.Add(vs);

    VisualStateManager.GetVisualStateGroups(MyGrid).Add(vsg);
}
```